# What exactly is HTML media API

Tags: html, api, video, media

I am reading a book called "Html5 media". In that the author shows an example of creating a video player. In that he he says that we can use 'HTML media API' to customize the controls, but he doesn't say what exactly it is. Also he says we will use Html Media Element interface.

What I don't understand is that, is Html media API and Html Media Element interface, part of Html5, are they something that some developer created, or are they a part of browsers?

I assume that Html Media Element is a kind of Html media API, but I don't understand what Html media API exactly is.

Can you please tell me about this?

Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Media API is a JavaScript API that is part of HTML5 that allows you to interact with the `audio` and `video` elements.

It provides a programming interface called [HTMLMediaElement](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#htmlmediaelement), which you have mentioned.

It is implemented within the browser, as long as both HTML5 audio and video are supported so you can just use them.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. It's hard to find this kind of information on Google. Mostly I got tutorials and long documentations. But this is good. Thank you again.